# Finding text in part of another cell and returning a different value

Tags: excel-formula

I need to take all the text in one cell and find it (even partially find it) in another column of cells. If there is a match it needs to return the value of another cell in the same row as the cell found.

For example:  In Sheet 1 Cell A1 has the text "John Smith".

Now in Sheet 2: Column D I need to find any cells in the column that have "John Smith" (chances are there will be only one "John Smith" so no need to worry about returning multiple values) and whatever cell in Column D Sheet2  contains "John Smith" needs to return the value that is in Columna A of sheet 2 of that same ROW.

I dont know how complicated this sounds but this process takes me 2 to 3 hours to do manually and just wanted to know if there is a way to do it faster through formulas.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Do you have any programming experience? And is this a task that needs to be done on a regular basis?

Comment: Read on `VLOOKUP`, `MATCH`, `INDEX`... functions. Hopefully that would be enough to get started, if still stuck, edit your post with your efforts.

Comment: I was tempted to post an answer based on `MATCH` (much simpler than what @Wolfish suggests) but then saw @zx8754's comment and thought I'd better just give you an additional hint: since you are not looking for an exact match against A1, but rather for any cell containing A1's value, you will have to use wildcards for your lookup value. Like so: `"*"&A1&"*"`, or arguably more readable: `CONCATENATE("*",A1,"*")`

Comment: @sls Simple is all relevant :) I suspect that the guy probably has a list of names to run through tbh. It would be far too easy for errors or wrong data to be returned if wildcards were used, we might have a John Smith, and a John Smithson, and a Johnathon Smithwick. I'd err on the side of caution personally.

Comment: @Wolfish Well, the OP does mention "even partially find it" (which I interpreted as a substring search), but I do agree that the "Smithson" vs "Smith" problem is a very valid argument against the naive wildcarding that I suggested. As for "simpler", I meant that it would be a short Excel formula instead of an hour's work of scripting/programming. I apologize if my comment offended you, it was not at all meant like that :)

Comment: @sls No, no offence taken. I just think the ability to make simple programs/scripts is a useful skill for anyone working with big data to have. Also, I'd hate to have to remember and type out that formula every time I wanted to run a query.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to utilise the scripting function of MS Excel, or even write an entirely separate program if this is a regular task. I'm going to give you a **pseudo-code** example in C# to show you the concept.

Now, we need to create a placeholder for the cell that contain's John's name:
`string nameCell (get; set;)`

And one for the data to be returned:
`string returnValue (get; set;)`

And now, to get things running.

First of all, we want to define the row that we're working with. We could also use a `foreach` loop to run through every single row: `foreach Row row in workBook`. But that's a little complicated, since I'm assuming you're new to programming.

So, we'll just use the one row for now. Let's call it `workingRow`:
`Row workingRow = workBook.row(1)`

See that number at the end of `workbook.row`? That tells us to look at row one.

Now, to look at the cell and see what it contains:

```
if (workingRow.nameCell = "John Smith")
    { 
       returnValue = workingRow.valueCell.ToString()
    }
else
    {
       returnValue = ""
    }
```

This small piece of code will tell the application to return the value in string format, whilst returning an empty string if "John Smith" is not found.

This should be fairly easy, perhaps an hour's work, to transform into workable material, whether you use a script inside Excel or build a completely separate program. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Exact match: `=INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!$D:$D,0))`

Partial match: `=INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH("*"&A1&"*",Sheet2!$D:$D,0))`

Starts-with match: `=INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH(A1&"*",Sheet2!$D:$D,0))`

MATCH

- finds the value of A1 ("John Smith") in column D, returns its position
- 0 indicates an exact match looking at each value and allowing wildcards, as opposed to a faster sorted search (a sorted search requires sorted data and returns a neighboring result when it can't find the one you want)
- "*" is a wildcard matching any text of any (even 0) length

INDEX

- Returns the value in column A at the position returned by MATCH

Answer (score -1):

1. use **[MATCH()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx)** function to find out which row in column D on Sheet 2 "John smith" appears. Make sure your column D is ordered alphabetically.
2. Use **[OFFSET()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/offset-function-HA102752910.aspx)** with cell A1 on Sheet 2 as reference (or the top DATA (not heading) cell of the column from which you want to display the data) and the result of the MATCH() function above as the "rows" argument

If you are struggling to achieve desired result, post what you have, and we can help further.